# How does one obtain a semiconductor's absorption coefficient from first principles?

Tags: semiconductor-physics, absorption

Is the absorption coefficient of a semiconducting material at a given wavelength obtainable from the material's band structure? If so, how? Are there any pedagogical papers you could recommend to help me understand this?

Comment: You tagged your question as [semiconductor-physics], but your question doesn't actually restrict itself to semiconductors. Could you edit to clarify?

Comment: yes i will edit thank you

Comment: Jacques Pankove, Optical Processes in Semiconductors, is a great introductory resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Fermi’s Golden Rule for a decent approximation. It won’t tell you in what situation it’s not valid, but it’s a good place to start. I’m not able to provide a reference at the moment, but you should be able to find it. For this, though, band structure is insufficient; you need the wavefunctions too. If you calculate the bandstructure via, e.g. tight-binding, then you get both eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

Comment: Thank you very much that's a great starting point.

Comment: @MalcolmRegan, if you accept the very first answer you get, you discourage others from answering. It's better to wait 24 hours to give people in all time zones a chance to answer (and improve your chance of getting the best answer possible).

Comment: Thank you. Good advice.

Comment: @MalcolmRegan I appreciate that you accepted my answer, but you may want to simply upvote and wait to accept until other people have had a chance to look at your question!

Comment: I appreciate that. Upvoted.